# Magento - configuring memcached

Tags: magento, memcached

I'm trying configure memcache using Magento.

Looking around in the code, I see some configuration in local.xml.additional and I've also seen examples of putting cache configuration in the local.xml

So, I left the local.xml.additional file alone and i put the following in local.xml

```
<cache>
<slow_backend>File</slow_backend>
<fast_backend>memcached</fast_backend>
<fast_backend_options>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <host>localhost</host>
      <port>11211</port>
      <persistent>1</persistent>
    </server>
  </servers>
</fast_backend_options>

<backend>memcached</backend>
<memcached>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <host>localhost</host>
      <port>11211</port>
      <persistent>1</persistent>
    </server>
  </servers>
</memcached>
</cache>
```

But running:

> telnet localhost 11211

Doesn't seem to be showing anything when I refresh the Magento pages.

Do I need any further configuration?

Thanks

UPDATE:

running:

> memcached -vv

and refreshing the pages, gives me the following output:

```
<29 new auto-negotiating client connection
29: Client using the ascii protocol
<29 stats
<30 new auto-negotiating client connection
30: Client using the ascii protocol
<30 stats
<31 new auto-negotiating client connection
31: Client using the ascii protocol
<31 get 28e_CORE_CACHE_OPTIONS
>31 END
<31 stats
<31 delete 28e_TRANSLATE_EN_GB_FRONTEND_1_DEFAULT_XXXXX
>31 NOT_FOUND
```

Does this mean that memcache is working on my store?

Thanks again

Comment: please format your config values so we can read the xml structure

Comment: @Jonathan Day please see my update question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are telnet'd into the memcached server, run `stats` and you will see how many cache hits and misses have occurred since starting the memcached service.  That should give you a good indication that Magento is hitting the cache.

Comment: Well, when I just run that command and then run 'stats' the 'STAT bytes_read' and the 'STAT bytes_written' seem to increase, not matter If I refresh the page or not. What should be happening when I refresh my magento store?

Answer (score 0):

you must makesure your PHP enviroment include memcached extension
however install it is very easy and quick
such as ubuntu & debian install via apt-get